# $user null but not null on json login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have a very weird behavior on symfony 6 with json login. Json login is configured like in their example.

I added the most simple Cors-handling

```
class CorsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $response->headers->add([
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type'
        ]);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse',
        ];
    }
}
```

Login Controller

```
class LoginController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/login', name: 'api_login')]
    public function login(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($user === null) {
            $this->json([
                'message' => 'Not found',
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $token = "token"; // some token logik follows

        $response = new JsonResponse([
            'user' => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
            'token' => $token,
        ]);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Again, basically straight out of their tutorial.

DB is also set up and a user was added beforehand. If I now want to login via a Rest App (I use Insomnia) everything works as expected. I get the user identifier (email) and token back.

But when I want to do the exact same thing via an Angular web app, I get the following message in the log: `[critical] Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUserIdentifier() on null`

```
    let data = {username: "test@test.de", password: "test123"};
    this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8000/login', data)
      .subscribe({
        next: (value) => {
          console.log(value);
        },
      });
```

Funny thing since I check if $user is null...
But the most funny thing is, if I change the `$user->getUserIdentifier()` call to just "`$user`" - it works and I get the whole User object returned (everything I defined in `json_serializable`)

Again, getUserIdentifier is from symfony itself

```
    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found out what's wrong.

1. No return

```
        if ($user === null) {
            $this->json([
                'message' => 'Not found',
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
```

I missed the `return` before `$this->json`, allowing the call to proceed even while `$user` was indeed `null`.

2. Preflight Cors

I honestly don't have too much experience and knowledge about cors and wasn't really aware about the preflight calls being done. But that was the problem.

```
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $method  = $request->getRealMethod();
        if ('OPTIONS' == $method) {
            $response = new Response();
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => ['onKernelResponse', 9999],
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 9999]
        ];
    }
```

I extended the CorsSubscriber to check for Method `OPTION` if it is not the main request and just sending a 200 to pass the preflight.
This helped me understand the logic behind it:

- https://gist.github.com/rordi/42de5982e877e1177a0e6a98ee8415ea
- https://www.upbeatproductions.com/blog/cors-pre-flight-requests-and-headers-symfony-httpkernel-component

Comment: Hey i get the same error but i would say CORS cant be the problem. I have the nelmico CORS bundle installed and the registration endpoint works fine. Anybody an idea? :)

Comment: Hmmm, for me it definitely was CORS. In Chrome Devtools the preflight also exited with CORS Error. Get Requests worked too in my case, maybe no preflights are sent with GET requests? Not a pro with CORS >_>

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation `check_path: api_login` is defined in the "security.yaml ".

In the ApiLoginController `#[route('/api/login', name:'api_login')]`

I wanted to change this to the path "`/login`".

Thereby I defined `check_path: login` in security.yaml

and in the controller `#[route('/login', name:'api_login')]`

However, the name must also be "login", like `#[route('/login', name:'login')]`

Comment: In check_path you can use the name (check_path: api_login) or the path (check_path: /login), so #[route('/login', name:'api_login')] would work with check_path: api_login since you are referring to the name, not the path. Changing both, path and name is of course valid, too.